# Процедура для создания N новых массивов в Питоне

Tags: python, массивы

Нужна процедура, которая при входном числе N создавала N отдельных массивов.

Answer (score 1):

Что-то такое нужно?

```
def create_arr(n):
    main_list = []
    for i in range(n):
        l_list = []
        main_list.append(l_list)
    return main_list

mylist = create_arr(5)
(mylist[0].append(10))
print(mylist)
```

Answer (score 1):

Для создания `N` новых списков:

```
lists = [[] for _ in range(N)]
```

Если создаваемые объекты неизменяемы, к примеру строки, то можно лаконичней синтаксис использовать:

```
strings = ["abc"] * N
```

Таким способом создаётся список, который ссылается `N` раз на одну и ту же строку. Поэтому не следует этот синтаксис с изменяемыми объектами такими как список использовать.